# How to change specific primary category name?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, yoast

I have more than one category name in the post and I want to change specific primary category name to be normal category and then normal category to be primary category.

Let's say I have sponsored category and fashion category. So, I want to switch fashion category to be primary category because I do not want to show /sponsored/ in the URL.

***Take Note: I have thousand of posts and I cannot switch the category name manually.***[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL and PHP you can run a foreach loop with all posts id that need to be updated.

A good starting point is an Excel file with all posts and its category ids that will be set as primary, so convert the spreadsheet to a json file to use in the PHP loop.

Below is the SQL query to do this:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = $new_primary_id WHERE post_id = $post_id AND meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category';
```

Where `$new_primary_id` is the id of the category that will be set as primary, and `$post_id` 
is the post id that will be updated.

Comment: If a post does not already have a category as primary you will need to insert it in the wp_postmeta table with the INSERT SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Yoast SEO Plugin there is the solution for you check here.

> https://wordpress.org/support/topic/bulk-change-primary-category/